# Why isn't it sufficient to just stage work-in-progress before switching branches? Why must I also commit?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-index

I'm working on some files in one branch (called `big_new_feature`). The files are not ready to commit, but I need to switch branches to make a quick fix in another branch (called `stable_branch`). Why can't I just stage the files in `big_new_feature` and check out `stable_branch`? Why do I have to actually commit the files in `big_new_feature` before switching to `stable_branch`?

Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: You don't need to commit. You can just do git stash save "some comment abt the change". Now your branch is clean, you can switch branch work on it then later come back to your original branch and do git stash apply with the change you had stashed

Comment: There are already two reasonable answers, but here's a much shorter one (with caveats that it's not the whole story): *there is only one index*, and files are staged and committed (and also merged) via the index.  So you have to clean the index before you can go make other independent commits on other branches.  Committing is the way to save-and-clean the index.  Note that `git stash` makes a commit (though actually *two* commits) for this same reason.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have to* commit those.  If the other branch hasn't *also* changed those files, then you can leave them staged.  Though you probably don't want to, because - well, because *now they'll be staged on the other branch* and it sounds like you don't want to commit them on the other branch.

```
% vi foo.c
% git add foo.c
% git checkout branch
M       foo.c
Switched to branch 'branch'
% git status
On branch branch
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   foo.c
```

So it's quite possible to do, but now `foo.c` is to be committed on *the other branch*, the one that you just switched over to in order to fix a bug.  Which is almost certainly not what you want.

I'm not sure why you're averse to committing in this situation.  That is certainly the far, far easiest situation to cope with, more so than stashing (though that would also be a possibility).

If you're concerned that you now have a half-baked "in progress" commit, then simply `commit --amend` your next commit to clean that up.  Or squash the commits before you push.

Answer (score 0):

When you switch branches the content of your tracked files will change to reflect the tip of the target branch.

If what you have in your working directory and stage does not conflict with the target branch state then no, you do not need to commit and you can switch branches as you desire.

But, I'm guessing that you are seeing this error message:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
>   by checkout

This is because when you stage content it is still present in the state of the files on your file-system.

**If what you have in your stage would conflict with the contents of the tip of your other branch then Git can't proceed because of the conflict.** Git doesn't know which side should win.

So, my advice, would be to do one of the following:

- create a separate topic branch to hold this temporary work
- stash your changes and re-apply them later
- go ahead and commit even if you are not ready...you can always amend or rework your commits prior to pushing